# Default arguments in Docker

Tags: docker

I am preparing a container that should be always called this way:

```
docker run -it --rm foo:bar arg1 arg2 ... argN
```

Where `arg1`, `arg2`, ..., `argN` are arguments that will be passed to the entry point. For a number of reasons, it just does not make sense to start this container without `-it` and `--rm`. Is it possible to set my container such that users do not need to pass the arguments `-it` and `--rm`? In other words, I want users to simply call:

```
docker run foo:bar arg1 arg2 ... argN
```

and `-it` and `--rm` will be implicit. I know I can simply wrap docker with a shell script that always adds those arguments, but I am wondering how/if docker deals with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering how/if docker deals with that

Not really: the [doc is clear](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)

> **By default** a container’s file system persists even after the container exits.
>   If instead you’d like Docker to automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits, you can add the `--rm` flag:

[`docker/compose` studies the possibility to run container with `--rm` by default](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/53), but since they are scripting the `docker run` commands, they can do that.

The same reasonning applies to -it (Keep STDIN open, pseudo tty allocation): those are runtime options which are not by default set.

I generally have [an alias for that](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/7aabadc2a333635ca0497e9b255353eb7b76e069/.bash_aliases#L24-L25)

```
alias dr='docker run -it --rm'
```

Comment: Actually my problem is how to make -it and --rm implicit. The entry point part is already working.

Comment: @Akira "Is it possible to set my container such that users do not need to pass these arguments": I thought you were referring to argsx! Sorry.